# Body Mass Index Calculator doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need help figuring out what's not working or what I'm doing wrong. There are a couple of errors I've been getting like in the last name part and in the scanner it skips a question and both weight and height are next to each other.

My teacher put that the Height has to be in that format but I'm not sure if the code I put really works for that.

My code is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BMRV1
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Gather Input
        System.out.print("Enter your name (first last): ");
        String fullName = in.next();


        System.out.print("Enter your weight in pounds (e.g. 175): ");
        String weightPoundsString = in.next();
        
        System.out.print("Enter your height in feet and inches (e.g. 5 11): ");
        String heightInchesString = in.next();


        //Parse numeric input
        int heightIn = Integer.parseInt(heightInchesString);
        int weightLbs = Integer.parseInt(weightPoundsString);

        //Convert height and weight
        double heightMeters = 39.3701 * heightIn;
        double weightKg = 0.45359237 * weightLbs;
        
        //Determine I
        // The BMI formula:
        //weight/height^2


      double BMI = weightKg / (heightMeters * heightMeters);
      
      String b;

        if (BMI < 18.5) {
            System.out.println("less than 18.5");
            b = "Underweight";
        } else if ((BMI) >= 18.5 || (BMI) <= 24.9) {
            System.out.println("between 18.5 and 24.9");
            b = "Normal";
        } else if (BMI >= 25 || BMI <= 29.9) {
            System.out.println("between 25 and 29.9");
            b = "Overweight";
        } else {
            System.out.println("greater than 30");
            b = "Obese";
        }


        //Display results
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("Body Mass Index Calculator\n");
        System.out.println("================================================================");


        //Note: numeric values displayed to one decimal place
        System.out.println("Name: " + fullName);
        System.out.println("Height (m): " + (int)(heightMeters));
        System.out.println("Weight (kg): " + (int)(weightKg));
        System.out.println("BMI: " + BMI);
        System.out.println("Category: " + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: "There are a couple of errors I've been getting like in the last name part and in the scanner it skips a question"  What's wrong the the "last name part"? What question is skipped? It would be helpful to show us your output AND the expected output so we can help you get from one to the other...

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your correctly, you want the questions to come on different lines. You should use System.out.println() method to print the questions. Read:[Difference between print() & println()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-print-and-println-in-java) And for height format, imo, it should be accepted in decimal format like 5.11 or read feet and inches separately to convert them into meter using appropriate formula. Read [Feet to Meter conversion](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Feet-to-Meters#:%7E:text=Because%20there%20are%203.28%20feet,0.3048%20meters%20in%20a%20foot.). Hope this helps!